# Як правильно добрати сполучник: вищий "чим", "ніж/аніж" або "за"?

Tags: сполучники

У фразах, де порівнюється деяка характеристика двох об'єктів, як правильно добирати сполучник у випадку, коли усі вони більш-менш підходять?

[ЧИМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/chym)¹, [НІЖ](http://sum.in.ua/s/nizh) (у значенні 2), [АНІЖ](http://sum.in.ua/s/anizh), [ЗА](http://sum.in.ua/s/za)² (у значенні 1.29)

- *Жито вище, **ніж** овес*; *День довший, **ніж** учорашній*
- *Жито вище **за** овес*; *День довший **за** учорашній*
- *Жито вище, **чим** овес*; *День довший, **чим** учорашній*

Цікавить покрокове правило, за допомогою якого можна добрати правильний сполучник.

**Оновлено:** у коментарях слушно нагадують, що є ще сполучники *від* і *як*:

- *Жито вище **від** овса*
- *Жито вище, **як** овес*

---

¹ Серед наведених значень, СУМ не включає того самого значення, що для інших наведених сполучників. Чи означає це, що використання *«чим»* у цьому контексті є русизмом?
² Чомусь СУМ вважає порівняльне *за* — прийменником, а не сполучником.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перш за все слід звернути увагу, що за інформацією, яку вдалося відшукати, зокрема, в таких джерелах:

[Посібник "Українська мова"](http://posibnyky.vntu.edu.ua/u_m/4.htm) з ресурсу Електронні посібники ВНТУ,

[Онлайн-курс "ЛАЙФХАКИ З УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ"](https://ukr-lifehacks.ed-era.com/8lec/stupeni.html) з курсів EdEra,

[Довідник з української мови](http://subject.com.ua/ukrmova/dovidnik/92.html) з ресурсу підручників,

[«Як ми говоримо»](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/stupenyuvannya-yakisnyh-prykmetnykiv) Бориса Антоненка-Давидовича,

[Рубрика "Уроки української"](http://fakty.ua/170948-professor-nataliya-shumarova-u-prikmetnik-v-sl-pij-lisij-bosij-chi-golij-nema-stupen-v-por-vnyannya) від професора Наталії Шумарової в газеті "Факти і коментарі",

вищий ступінь порівняння прикметників звичайно вимагає після себе
**прийменників** ***від***, ***за***, ***над***, ***проти***, ***порівняно з*** з відповідними відмінками або **сполучників** ***як***, ***ніж (аніж)***:

«*Страх — більший **від** переполоху*» (М. Номис);

«*Це буде мій твір, може, кращий **за** ті, які ви читали*» (М. Коцюбинський);

«*У дружбі він свої чуття гартує, у нім сильніше «наше» **над** «моє»* (І. Муратов);

*«У нашім раї на землі нічого кращого немає, **як** тая мати молодая з своїм дитяточком малим»* (Т. Шевченко);

«*Повітря в горах — дуже прозоре, отже, й видимість тут стала набагато краща, **ніж** на рівнині*» (О. Гончар).

Стверджується, що відступи від цього правила, коли, аби утворити вищий ступінь прикметника, вдаються до прислівникової форми з родовим відмінком слова: «*У зайця задні ноги довше передніх*»; «*Він розумніше свого брата*», а також до вживання конструкцій із займенником/сполучником ***чим***, є ненормативними і помилковими.

В той же час СУМ зазначає два випадки (один з яких позначено як розмовний), коли вживання сполучника ***чим*** є нормативним для порівняльних конструкцій:

[ЧИМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/chym)

> 2. спол. порівняльний. **Вводить у складне речення порівняльне підрядне або член речення, маючи в наступному реченні або частині його
>      співвідносне слово *тим*, рідше *то***. *Цілину хіба орють парою?
>      ну, ну! Так і у господарстві: **чим** більше рук, **то** і швидче
>      [швидше] діло поспіє* (Квітка-Основ'яненко, II, 1956, 122); ***Чим***
>      ближче під'їздив Андрій до села, **тим** серце його билось скоріше і
>      сильніше (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 449);
>
> //  розм. **Уживається після слів у ступені порівняння і приєднує
>   речення, з яким що-небудь порівнюється**; **ніж**. *Скілько вже в мене
>   є початого, та не покінченого?.. Скоріш море діжде погоди, **чим**
>   моя робота — кінця* (Квітка-Основ'яненко, V, 1955, 341); *Він закидав
>   книжки, брав у руки вила і обіцяв сам собі, що краще буде крутити
>   бикам хвости, **чим** поїде на велелюдне позорисько, тобто поступати
>   в університет* (Григорій Тютюнник, Вир, 1964, 52).

Отже, якщо говорити про алгоритм ("покрокове правило"), як просить автор запитання, то я б сформулювала так.

1. Визначаємо, порівняння має бути прийменниковим чи сполучниковим.
2. Для прийменникового порівняння обираємо з-поміж ***від***, ***за***, ***над***, ***проти***, ***порівняно з***. За бажанням автора. Прийменникові порівняльні конструкції зазвичай вживаються в межах одного простого речення (навіть якщо це просте речення є частиною складного).
3. Для сполучникового порівняння обираємо ***як*** або ***ніж(аніж)***. Пам'ятаємо, що перед цими сполучниками ставиться кома, на відміну від конструкцій із прийменниковим порівнянням. Зрозуміло, що підрядні порівняльні речення можуть додаватися тільки за допомогою зазначених сполучників, а не прийменників.
4. Для вживання порівняльної конструкції з **чим** перевіряємо на відповідність ознакам, зазначеним у СУМ.