# Вживання прийменника "в" у реченні "... була четвертою в десяти секундах після..."

Tags: прийменники

Прийменник у/в в основному вживається, коли мова іде про простір, місце, конкретний час. У фрагменті речення

> ... була четвертою в десяти секундах після...

він вживається по відношенню до інтервалу часу.

У [словнику](http://sum.in.ua/s/v) я знайшов кілька варіантів вживання, що стосується часового відношення:

> 20. Уживається при означенні часу, в який відбувається дія або коли наявний який-небудь стан.
> 21. із знах. в. Уживається при означенні проміжку часу, протягом якого відбувається дія.
> 22. із знах. в., заст. Уживається при означенні проміжку часу, після закінчення якого відбувається дія.

Найближчим виглядає випадок 21. Але тут дії, як такої, немає (принаймні, на мою думку).

Чи є таке вживання прийменника у/в правильним? Якщо так, то чи підпадає воно під варіант 21?

Comment: Дія, як на мене, тут якраз є. Просто недосказана: «була четвертою в десяти секундах після» = «*фінішувала* четвертою в десяти секундах після» (чи що там за контекстом). Але немає з.в., тому 21 і 22 не підходять.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Це за Вашим посиланням значення № 23:

> Кількісні відношення
>
> **23.** *із знах. і місц. в.* Уживається при означенні міри, ваги, розміру і взагалі кількісної ознаки кого-, чого-небудь чи вартості чогось.
>
> - Старший стріля з лука: як попужне у п'ять пуд стрілою, то, неначе вогнем, палить військо (Олекса Стороженко, I, 1957, 70);
> - Подивилась [Харитина] — паперик, аж там бумажка з царицею, аж у сто карбованців (Ганна Барвінок, Опов.., 1902, 256);
> - А се, справді, перше говорив, що й хати нові поставлю у три віконця, а потім — то й старі розвалились! (Марко Вовчок, I, 1955, 66);
> - Та прийшов вже не один, а в п'ятьох стах козаків при двох сотниках (Данило Мордовець, I, 1958, 141);
> - На стінах міських будинків уже виростало величезне, в людський зріст «Л», з товстою, як рука, стрілкою дороговказу (Олесь Гончар, III, 1959, 74).

- Вона фінішувала четвертою, в 10 секундах після Трецької.

Під варіант 21 не підпадає, тому що:

- немає проміжку часу;
- немає знахідного відмінку.

Щодо правильності точно не знаю. Я б, мабуть, написав «вона фінішувала четвертою, [за 10 секунд після](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q="%D0%B7%D0%B0+*+%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4+%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F") Трецької» або «вона фінішувала четвертою, через 10 секунд після Трецької». Але, мабуть, всі три в тій чи іншій мірі правильні.

Comment: Можна б ще в інструментальному відмінку: *«десять**ма** секундами пізніше»*, але тоді скупчення двох числівників було б негарне. Думаю, саме це і спричинило ту форму, якою автор скористався.

Comment: @bytebuster, «десятьма секундами пізніше за *Ім'ярек*»?

Comment: або *«ніж»* + називний — [тут з'ясовували](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/630/) порівняльні сполучники. Щоправда, так і нема відповіді… :)